# Why different objects are assigned the same value?

Tags: javascript

Why different objects plyers[o] and plyers[1] are assigned the same value? Although there should be a difference of 1

```
var player = {
    'money': 1,
    'increase' : 10
}

var players = [];


for (var i=0;i<2;i++){
    players[i] = player;
}
for (var i=0;i<3;i++){
    for (var j=0;j<players.length;j++){
        players[j]['money'] += (players[j]['increase']+j)
        console.log(players[0].money + ' ___0')
        console.log(players[1].money + ' ___1')
    }
}
```

console :

```
11 ___0 
11 ___1 
22 ___0 
22 ___1 
32 ___0 
32 ___1
```

Comment: You are assigning references not values, so any change to player[0] will effect player[1] as both refer to the same player object. You must copy your object or try to create your 'var player' in first for loop. That way in every iteration a new player instance will be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
players[i] = player;
```

you are not creating a copy of `player` and assign it to `players[i]`, but making `players[i]` refer to `player` object. So, all the elements of the array are pointing to the same object.

What you might want to do is to clone the objects, like this

```
players[i] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(player));
```

**Note:** The cloning method I mentioned will work properly only when there are no functions in the objects and no inheritance chain. You can follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/1903116) to know more about other ways to clone a JavaScript object.

Comment: @sankrish—there are many issues with copying objects. You need to be aware of exactly what you want to do with a copy, e.g. do you want to copy object properties too or just reference them? What should be done with DOM objects? Or other host objects? Dates? Functions?